# Closed form for $\sum_{m\geq 2, n\geq 2}\frac1{m^n-1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, closed-form

> Is there a nice closed form for $\displaystyle \sum_{\substack{m\geq 2\\ n\geq 2}}\frac1{m^n-1}$ ?

It's easy to prove that $\displaystyle \sum_{\substack{m\geq 2\\ n\geq 2}}\frac1{m^n} = 1$ by summing first over $n$ (geometric sum) and then over $m$ (telescopic series).

It can be proven that $ \sum_{q \in Q} \frac1{q-1}=1 \quad \text{where } Q=\{m^n, n\geq 2, m\geq 2\}$. A natural extension is to compute $\displaystyle \sum_{m\geq 2, n\geq 2}\frac1{m^n-1}$.

Here's what I've noticed:
$$\begin{align}
\sum_{\substack{m\geq 2\\ n\geq 2}}\frac1{m^n-1}&=\sum_{\substack{m\geq 2\\ n\geq 2}}\frac{1/m^n}{1-1/m^n}=\sum_{\substack{m\geq 2\\ n\geq 2}}\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac1{m^{nk}}\\
&=\sum_{m\geq 2}\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{1}{m^k(m^k-1)} = \sum_{m\geq 2}\sum_{k\geq 1}\left(\frac 1{m^k-1}-\frac 1{m^k}\right)
\end{align}$$
but that looks like a dead-end.

According to Mathematica, an approximation of the limit is $1.130396449$.

Comment: Why did you delete https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2894258/proof-of-sum-m-geq-2-n-geq-2-frac1mn-1-1 ?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown the equality I had written is wrong, since $\sum _{n=2}^{10} \sum _{m=2}^{10} \frac{1}{m^n-1}$ evaluates to something greater than $1.02$ What's true is $\sum_{q \in Q} \frac1{q-1}=1 \quad \text{where } Q=\{m^n, n\geq 2, m\geq 2\}$.